# How can I expand a table with a range between two dates as a new column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table for example:

| Start date | End date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | value1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | value2 |

The output I want would be this:

| Start date | End date | value | Date between |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | value1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | value1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | value1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | value2 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | value2 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | value2 | 2022-01-04 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `JOIN` to your calendar table. If you don't have one, create one (they are an invaluable tool). If you "must" do this on the fly, use a [Tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested, you need a calendar table.
Here is how you can create one

```
create table calendar (id int identity, cdate date not null)
```

and fill it one time like this (choose a enddate far enough in the future, and a startdate far enough in the past so you won't have to add rows to this table anymore

```
;WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL                 --startdate  enddate
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '20220101', '20220301')) 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --up to 1,000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '20220101') AS Date
    FROM Tally T)
insert into calendar (cdate)    
SELECT D.Date
FROM Dates D
```

So now you have a table called `calendar` where you can join on, the query you need is now very simple

```
select t.startdate,
       t.enddate,
       t.value,
       c.cdate as datebetween
from   mytable t
  left join calendar c on c.cdate >= t.startdate
                      and c.cdate <= t.enddate
```

[Click on this DBFiddle to see how it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c49ecf9cc23345b95909da185a0f1e97)

Comment: You are a wizard! Thank you a lot